# Python create instance of class using string manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I wrote Class and created two lists. The first for the users and the second for the user-attributes.

I would now like to loop trough the two lists in order to create multiple Class instances with the respective data.

```
class Employee:
    
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'


emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', '50000')
emp_2 = Employee('Test', 'User', '60000')
```

by printing `print(amp_1.email)` i can create the instance of the class:

will print
`Corey.Schafer@company.com`

Now i dont want to write it out manually so i want to loop trough it:

```
for user in users:
    for user_atr in user_atrs:
        print(user + '.' + user_atr)
```

will print:

```
empy_1.first
empy_1.last
empy_1.pay
empy_1.email
empy_2.first
empy_2.last
empy_2.pay
empy_2.email
```

Instead of:

```
Corey
Schafer
50000
Corey.Schafer@email.com
Test
User
60000
Test.User@email.com
```

How can i use that loop to actually create the instance of the class and not just the blueprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Basic Solution

- a list of `string` of the users : `['emp_1', 'emp_2']`
- a list of `string` that are attributs name `['first', 'last', 'pay', 'email']`

Then use the builtin method `globals()` to get the variable and  `getattr(obj, name, default)`  but that isn't nice and requires to type variable names

```
emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000)
emp_2 = Employee('Test', 'User', '60000')

for user in ['emp_1', 'emp_2']:
    for user_atr in ['first', 'last', 'pay', 'email']:
        print(getattr(globals()[user], user_atr))
```

---

---

#### Better Solution

- a list of `Employee` instances  : `[emp_1, emp_2]`
- Access object properties with  `__dict__`  (`key` is name, `value` are property's value)

```
for user in [emp_1, emp_2]:
    for user_atr in user.__dict__.values():
        print(user_atr)

Corey
Schafer
50000
Corey.Schafer@company.com
...
```

To read both name and value at the same time

```
for user in [emp_1, emp_2]:
    for user_atr in user.__dict__.items():
        print(user_atr)

('first', 'Corey')
('last', 'Schafer')
('pay', 50000)
('email', 'Corey.Schafer@company.com')
...
```

Comment: Jesus, i didn't. I was completely blind. Sorry!! Of course

Answer (score 1):

```
class Employee:
    
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'


emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', '50000')
emp_2 = Employee('Test', 'User', '60000')

users = {"emp_1": emp_1,
    "emp_2": emp_2}

for user in users.values():
    for attribute in list(user.__dict__.keys()):
        print(f"{name}.{attribute}")
```

This will do that for you by storing the users in a dictionary with the name of the user as the dictionary key and then using the `__dict__` attribute from the `Employee` class to get a dictionary of all atributes and then printing the name of each attribute from that dictionary.

If you are trying to print the value of each of these attributes then it can be changed to the following:

```
users = {"emp_1": emp_1,
    "emp_2": emp_2}

for name, user in users.items():
    for attribute in list(user.__dict__.keys()):
        print(getattr(user,attribute))
```

Using this method means that any more attributes added to the employee class will be printed also.